# Amazon Api Gateway service proxy for Dynomodb

Tags: amazon-web-services

I followed this tutorial to implement DynamoDB endpoint proxy service via API Gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

I manage to implement the PutItem. The Query gives me following error:

> "message": "ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or
>   more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain
>   an empty string for key :v1"

My mapping template is : 
        `{
        "TableName": "dgm-visit",
        "PrimaryKey": "date",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "date = :v1",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":v1": {
                "S": "$input.params('date')"
            }
         }
     }`

Comment: Can you please share the request path of the API? Is the date a querystring or path parameter?

Comment: date is path paramter :

Comment: /dgmvisit3/{date} - GET - Integration Request . I am doing a query and my date is a string in dynamodb . For example, date is 11/01/18 in dynamodb . It is my primary partition key and I also have date-index . I have three attributes for date 11/01/18 that I want to query.

Comment: I changed two items and it works now! First, I changed attribute date to selectdate. Date is a reserved word. Second, path does not like 11/01/18 as string so I changed it to November 1, 2018.